# Why does this combination of foreign + primary key produce a Postgres deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, postgresql, database-deadlocks

Start with these two tables and this an initial record for `c`:

```sql
create table c
(
    id   serial primary key,
    name varchar not null
);

create table e
(
    id   varchar                  not null,
    c_id bigint references c (id) not null,
    name varchar                  not null,
    primary key (id, c_id)
);

insert into c (name) values ('deadlock test');
```

Thread 1:

```sql
begin;
select * from c where id = 1 for update;
insert into e (id, c_id, name) VALUES ('bar', 1, 'second') on conflict do nothing ;
commit;
```

Thread 2:

```sql
begin;
insert into e (id, c_id, name) VALUES ('bar', 1, 'first') on conflict do nothing ;
commit;
```

Execution order is:

- Thread 1: begin
- Thread 2: begin
- Thread 1: lock `c`
- Thread 2: insert `e`
- Thread 1: insert `e` <-- deadlock

*Why does this happen?*

Adding a lock to `c` on Thread 2 of course avoids the deadlock, but it's not clear to me why. Also interesting is that if the row in `e` exists before Thread 1 or 2 run, then no deadlock happens.

I suspect there are at least two things going on:

- The primary key creates a unique constraint that causes some sort of locking on `e` that I don't understand, even with the `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING`.
- The foreign key on `c_id` results in some sort of trigger causing a lock on `c` when a new record is inserted (or when `c_id` is updated, I presume).

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To maintain integrity, every insert on `e` will lock the referenced row in `c` with a `KEY SHARE` lock. This keeps any concurrent transaction from deleting the row in `c` or modifying the primary key.

Such a `KEY SHARE` lock conflicts with the `UPDATE` lock session 1 took explicitly (see [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/explicit-locking.html#ROW-LOCK-COMPATIBILITY)), so the `INSERT` of session 2 blocks - but it already inserted (and locked) an index tuple in the primary key index of `e`.

Now session 1 wants to insert a row with the same primary key that session 2 inserted, so it will block on the lock just taken by session 2, and the deadlock is perfect.

You probably wonder why `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` doesn't change the behavior. But PostgreSQL doesn't get there, because to know if there is a conflict, session 1 will have to wait until it knows if session 2 commits or rolls back. So the deadlock happens before we know if there will be a conflict or not.

Comment: Wonderful explanation, thank you! Just one question: can you point me to the docs that explain the first paragraph, about how a `KEY SHARE` lock is established when inserting `e` records?

Comment: Thanks to open source, I can show you [the patch that introduced the feature](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=0ac5ad5134f2769ccbaefec73844f8504c4d6182).

Comment: The patch is interesting but I’m really curious about where in the docs it is made clear that a key share lock is established on FK relationships. I think reading it a few times would better help me understand more about Postgres locks. Thanks!

Comment: Beyond a certain level of detail you won't find information in the documentation any more. In a way, the documentation is continued in source comments and READMEs. That's why I pointed you to the patch, because that detail is not covered by the documentation.